# Editing one of many dict's in plist file?

Tags: ios

On my root view controller (`UITableViewController`), I've read into `NSMutableDictionary` the root dict from the `plist` file and have displayed in the table, keys for all dict's within the root dict. When the user taps on any of the key, I pass the dictionary (again as an `NSMutableDictionary`) to that key to a new detail view controller where this dictionary is displayed.

Now when a particular detail of this dictionary is edited I would like to update the dictionary object and save to the `plist` file.

1- I'm not even able to update the `NSMutableDictionary` object e.g. using its `- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey` method.

2- Is it possible to read into an `NSMutableDictionary` a `plist` file in the order as it is in the `plist` file because I would want to allow the user to re-arrange their views (hence update plist file accordingly).

XML structure:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>abc</key>
        <dict><key></key><string></string></dict>
        <key>ijk</key>
        <dict><key></key><string></string></dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Help will be really appreciated!
Thanks
Bilal.

Comment: Can you post the code that "passes" the `NSMutableDictionary` between your `UIViewController` subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

To answer part 2 of the question, a dictionary is the wrong data structure to use when you want to maintain a particular ordering of the contents.  A dictionary is a key-value structure, not an ordered collection.  You may want an NSMutableArray instead.